# Cannot import parse_url in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, hiveql

I have this sql query, for hiveql in pyspark:

```py
spark.sql('SELECT split(parse_url(page.viewed_page, "PATH"), "/")[1] as path FROM df')
```

And I would like to translate into functional query like:

```py
df.select(split(parse_url(col('page.viewed_page'), 'HOST')))
```

but when I import the `parse_url` function I get:

```
----> 1 from pyspark.sql.functions import split, parse_url

ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_url' from 'pyspark.sql.functions' (/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py)
```

Could you point me in the right direction to import the parse_url function.

Cheers

Comment: Also also use `expr`: `df.select(expr("split(parse_url(page.viewed_page, 'HOST'))"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parse_url` is a Hive UDF, so you need to enable Hive Support by while creating the SparkSession object()

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Then your following query should work:

```
spark.sql('SELECT split(parse_url(page.viewed_page, "PATH"), "/")[1] as path FROM df')
```

If your Spark is `<2.2`:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
hivContext = HiveContext(sc)

query = 'SELECT split(parse_url(page.viewed_page, "PATH"), "/")[1] as path FROM df'

hivContext.sql(query) # this will work
sqlContext.sql(query) # this will not work
```

#### EDIT:

[parse_url](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#parse_url) is a SparkSQL builtin from Spark v2.3. It's not available in `pyspark.sql.functions` as of yet (11/28/2020). You can still use it on a pyspark dataframe by using [selectExpr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr) like this:

```
df.selectExpr('parse_url(mycolumn, "HOST")')
```